# Best and Faster way for generate DAO class

Tags: php, pdo, dao

I have reed a lot of pages about how generate a DAO class using PDO but I haven't find a good and faster way for obtain it.

Suppose we have a Database table called Animals with this structure

```
CREATE TABLE animals
(
    idAnimal int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(20),
    dateOfBirth DATETIME
);
```

A good way of development is create two class: `Animals` and `AnimalsDAO` like this

```
class Animals{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    public $idAnimal;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $name;
    /**
     * @var DateTime
     */
    public $dateOfBirth;

    /**
     * Animals constructor.
     * @param int $idAnimal
     * @param string $name
     * @param DateTime $dateOfBirth
     */
    public function __construct($idAnimal, $name, DateTime $dateOfBirth) {
        $this->idAnimal = $idAnimal;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->dateOfBirth = $dateOfBirth;
    }

}
```

In the `AnimalsDAO` generally there is the method for insert and retrive the object from database.
And in this class there is already an ORM problems (ORM Object Relation Mapping) because the fetch method of PDO don't work properly with object casting
For years I have develop DAO in this way

```
class ClienteDAO {
    /**
     * @param $idAnimal integer
     * @return Cliente
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static function getClienteById($idAnimal ){

        $q="SELECT * FROM animals WHERE idAnimal =:idanim";
        $sth=PDOConnection::instance()->prepare($q);
        $sth->bindParam(':idanim', $idCliente,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        if($sth->execute()==0)
            throw new PDOException("ERROR EXECUTE");
        if($sth->rowCount()!=1)
            throw new PDOException("ERROR ROW NUMBERS");
        $row=$sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
        $row[2]=new DateTime($row[2]);
        return new Animals(...$row);
    }
}
```

So then if I change add or remove a database field, I have to only edit the variable in the `Animal` class, regenerate the constructor (I use PhpStorm) and edit eventually the rows after the fetch

Exist a best and faster way for generate the DAO class ?
(Another way is retrive the class attribute name and use the fetch Names method but there is again the casting problems with dateTime columns)

The problems is more complicate when there is an inheritance into DataBase solved with association and the inheritance is in the php class

[ER DIAGRAM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcS8L.jpg)

And the database structure is translated in 
[DATABASE STRUCTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPKKl.png)

Obviously, on the php side there is a father super class and two child class (extends the fater class)

How is the faster way for generate the DAO method for the child ?

Comment: I typically have a class static `fromRow($row)` in the entity class, in this class `Animal`, which is invoked from the Entity DAO class. The __construct in entity class is private, so i can hide critical DB fields i never want to expose (id is one). I can only instantiate with `Animals::fromRow($row)`, where $row is the result of some DB fetch.  My way of doing this ... TIMTOWTDI

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Thanks for your answer, I think every person does it in a different way becouse there is a lack of a fetchmethod more configurable.
But in the case of large database, a lot of class,inheritance a single database field edit requires us change many code and method

Comment: @YvesLeBorg can you explain me more about how you generate `Animals::fromRow()` method??

Comment: done. The actual signature of the entity class static method is `fromAssociativeArray($row)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per OP req, an example from my Codebase

**Device**

```
namespace DAO;

use common\Context;
use enums\DeviceOStypeEnum;
use NAO\Inbound\IBDeviceSpec;
use NAO\Outbound\OBDevice;
use protocols\IClassInit;
use protocols\ITokenizer;
use traits\ClassInitTrait;

class Device extends AbstractDataObject implements IClassInit , ITokenizer
{

    const APPLE_PERMANENT_DEVICE_GUID    = "f8d55ac7-6e6a-4a0c-a5ec-20df1f384d62";
    const GOOGLE_PERMANENT_DEVICE_GUID   = "788996ff-5da3-47f2-9601-3f9ae79b51aa";

    use ClassInitTrait;

    /** @var  int $id */
    protected $id;
    /** @var  string $deviceGuid */
    var $deviceGuid;
    /** @var  DeviceOStypeEnum $osType */
    var $osType;
    /** @var  Version $osVersion */
    var $osVersion;
    /** @var  string $manufacturer */
    var $manufacturer;
    /** @var  string $modelCode */
    var $modelCode;
    /** @var  \DateTime $createdOn */
    var $createdOn;
    /**@var \DateTime $lastSeen */
    var $lastSeen;
    /** @var  bool $active */
    var $active;
    /** @var $isPhone */
    var $isPhone;
    /** @var  App $app */
    var $app;

    public static function postInit($c , $isTraceEnabled , $isPDOuser)
    {
    }

    /**
     * Device constructor.
     *
     * @param int $id
     * @param string $deviceGuid
     * @param DeviceOStypeEnum $osType
     * @param Version $osVersion
     * @param string $manufacturer
     * @param string $modelCode
     * @param \DateTime $createdOn
     * @param \DateTime $lastSeen
     * @param App $app
     * @param bool $isPhone
     * @param bool $active
     */
    public function __construct($id , $deviceGuid ,
                                $osType , $osVersion , $manufacturer , $modelCode ,
                                \DateTime $createdOn , \DateTime $lastSeen ,
                                $active , $isPhone , $app)
    {
        $this->id           = $id;
        $this->deviceGuid   = $deviceGuid;
        $this->osType       = $osType;
        $this->osVersion    = $osVersion;
        $this->manufacturer = $manufacturer;
        $this->modelCode    = $modelCode;
        $this->createdOn    = $createdOn;
        $this->lastSeen     = $lastSeen;
        $this->active       = $active;
        $this->app          = $app;
        $this->isPhone      = $isPhone;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $row
     *
     * @return Device
     */
    public static function fromAssociativeArray($row)
    {
        $OStype     = new DeviceOStypeEnum($row['os_type']);
        $osVersion  = Version::fromString($row['os_version']);
        $createdOn  = dateTimeFromSQLquery($row['created_on']);
        $lastSeen   = dateTimeFromSQLquery($row['last_seen']);
        $active     = (bool) $row['active'];
        $deviceGuid = binaryGuidAsStringGuid($row['device_guid_bin']);
        $isPhone    = (bool) $row['is_phone'];
        $app        = AppDAO::applicationWithId($row['app_id']);
        return new Device(
            $row['id'] ,
            $deviceGuid ,
            $OStype ,
            $osVersion ,
            $row['manufacturer'] ,
            $row['model_code'] ,
            $createdOn ,
            $lastSeen ,
            $active ,
            $isPhone ,
            $app
        );

    }

// plus a whole bunch of business logic after
```

**DeviceDAO (partiel)**

```
namespace DAO;

use enums\DeviceOStypeEnum;
use NAO\Inbound\IBDeviceSpec;
use protocols\IClassInit;
use traits\ClassInitTrait;

class DeviceDAO implements IClassInit
{

    use ClassInitTrait;

    /**
     * @param string $guid
     * @param DeviceOStypeEnum $osType
     * @param Version $osVersion
     * @param string $manufacturer
     * @param string $modelCode
     * @param boolean $isPhone
     * @param App $app
     *
     * @return Device|null
     */
    public static function insert($guid ,
                                  DeviceOStypeEnum $osType , Version $osVersion ,
                                  $manufacturer , $modelCode ,
                                  $isPhone , App $app)
    {
        $pdo       = self::getClassPDO();
        $q         = $e = null;
        $createdOn = now();
        $lastSeen  = now();
        $sql       = <<<SQL
INSERT INTO Device SET device_guid_bin = :guid, 
os_type = :ost, 
os_version = :version ,
manufacturer=:manufacturer,model_code=:model,
created_on=:co, last_seen = :lastseen ,  active=1, `is_phone`=:phone, `app_id` = :appid

SQL;
        $device    = null;
        try {
            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $q->bindValue('guid' , stringGuidAsBinaryGuid($guid) , \PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $q->bindValue('ost' , $osType->stringValue , \PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $q->bindValue('version' , $osVersion->__toString() , \PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $q->bindValue('manufacturer' , $manufacturer , \PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $q->bindValue('model' , $modelCode , \PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $q->bindValue('co' , dateTimeAsSQLstring($createdOn) , \PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $q->bindValue('lastseen' , dateTimeAsSQLstring($lastSeen) , \PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $q->bindValue('phone' , $isPhone , \PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
            $q->bindValue('appid' , $app->getId() , \PDO::PARAM_INT);
            if ($q->execute()) {
                $id     = $pdo->lastInsertId();
                $device = new Device(
                    $id , $guid ,
                    $osType , $osVersion ,
                    $manufacturer , $modelCode ,
                    $createdOn , $lastSeen , true , $isPhone ,
                    $app
                );
            } else {
                self::logQueryFail("Unknown error while inserting a device" , $q , $e);
            }

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            self::logQueryFail("Error while inserting a Device" , $q , $e);
        }
        return $device;

    }

    /**
     * @param IBDeviceSpec $spec
     *
     * @return Device|null
     */
    public static function insertWithDeviceSpec(IBDeviceSpec $spec)
    {
        $app = AppDAO::applicationWithGuid($spec->appGuid);
        return self::insert(
            $spec->deviceGuid , $spec->osType , $spec->osVersion , $spec->manufacturer , $spec->modelCode ,
            $spec->isPhone , $app
        );

    }

    /**
     * @param Device $device
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function update(Device $device)
    {

        if (!$device) {
            self::getClassLogger()->error("Attemptempt to update null Device");
            return false;
        }
        $pdo = self::getClassPDO();
        $q   = $e = null;

        $sql = <<<SQL
UPDATE  Device 
SET device_guid_bin = :guid, 
os_type = :ost, 
os_version = :version ,
manufacturer=:manufacturer,
model_code=:model,
created_on=:co, 
last_seen = :lastseen,  
active=:ac,   
`is_phone`=:phone, 
`app_id`=:appid
WHERE 
id=:id

SQL;
        try {
            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $q->bindValue('id' , $device->getId() , \PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $q->bindValue('guid' , stringGuidAsBinaryGuid($device->deviceGuid) , \PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $q->bindValue('ost' , $device->osType->stringValue , \PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $q->bindValue('version' , $device->osVersion->__toString() , \PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $q->bindValue('manufacturer' , $device->manufacturer , \PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $q->bindValue('model' , $device->modelCode , \PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $q->bindValue('co' , dateTimeAsSQLstring($device->createdOn) , \PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $q->bindValue('lastseen' , dateTimeAsSQLstring($device->lastSeen) , \PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $q->bindValue('ac' , $device->active , \PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
            $q->bindValue('phone' , $device->isPhone , \PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
            $q->bindValue('appid' , $device->app->getId() , \PDO::PARAM_INT);
            if ($q->execute()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                self::logQueryFail("Unknown error while updating a device" , $q , $e);
            }

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            self::logQueryFail("Error while inserting a Device" , $q , $e);
        }
        return false;

    }

    /**
     * @param string $guid
     *
     * @return Device|null
     */

    public static function deviceWithDeviceGuid($guid)
    {
        if (!$guid) return null;
        $pdo    = self::getClassPDO();
        $q      = $e = null;
        $device = null;

        $sql = <<<SQL
SELECT * FROM Device WHERE device_guid_bin=:gu  
SQL;
        try {

            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $q->bindValue(':gu' , stringGuidAsBinaryGuid($guid) , \PDO::PARAM_STR);
            if ($q->execute()) {
                $rows = $q->fetchAll();
                if (count($rows) == 0) {
                    self::getClassLogger()->trace(__FUNCTION__ . " Query for device [$guid] returned no device");
                } else if (count($rows) > 1) {
                    self::logQueryFail(__FUNCTION__ . " : Query for device returned multiple rows ! [$guid]" , $q , $e);
                } else {
                    $row    = $rows[0];
                    $device = Device::fromAssociativeArray($row);
                }
            } else {
                self::logQueryFail(__FUNCTION__ . " : Error while fetching device with guid[$guid]" , $q , $e);
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            self::logQueryFail(__FUNCTION__ . " : Error while fetching device with guid[$guid]" , $q , $e);
        }

        return $device;
    }

}
// etc ...
```

**The SQL**

```
--
-- Table structure for table `Device` 
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Device`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `Device`
(
`id`              bigint(20)                               NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`app_id`          bigint(20)                               NOT NULL,
`os_type`         enum ('android','iPhone OS','iOS','nix') NOT NULL,
`os_version`      varchar(11)                                       DEFAULT NULL,
`manufacturer`    varchar(50)                                       DEFAULT NULL,
`model_code`      varchar(50)                                       DEFAULT NULL,
`created_on`      datetime                                 NOT NULL,
`last_seen`       datetime                                 NOT NULL,
`active`          tinyint(4)                               NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`is_phone`        tinyint(4)                               NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`device_guid_bin` varbinary(16)                                     DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `idx_device_guid` (`device_guid_bin`),
KEY `idx_app` (`app_id`),
KEY `idx_active` (`active`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_device_app` FOREIGN KEY (`app_id`) REFERENCES `App` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB
  AUTO_INCREMENT = 68
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

**notes**

- Have not shown functions like `dateTimeFromSQLquery` etc ... all in my global functions. I use such to normalize DB. Time is always UTC at rest (DB), and in flight (API)
- For relationships, i systematically prefer a lazy load method (not in the code shown)
- SomeObjectDAO encapsulates completely caching (or not).

Comment: Thanks for you replay, I hope in other replay In order to choice what is the best method 
If nobody replay in 7 days I'll choose it as answer.
Stay tuned also for read other developers choice and help me for highlight the difference.
if you think my question is interesting  help me with a plus